# Output caching, VaryByParam/VaryByCustom

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

OK, there seem to be no end to the number of articles that sing the praises of output caching and how much it will speed up your website. I have now read hundreds of articles and Q&As on the topic, but I still can't seem to make it work. (I think output caching might be stealing my soul)

My requirements are pretty simple, I have 3 pages that I would like to cache based on parameters: Home, Results, and Details. I also have a small area of the page that needs to be varied by user. I also need to cache to a central repository and I have chosen redis to hold my data. I should also mention that this is still an old web forms app.

My original approach was to attempt to supply my own custom string using the "VaryByCustom" option. The Microsoft page seems to make this look simple:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ecf4420.aspx

This requires placing an overridden method "GetVaryByCustomString" in the global.asax file. The problem is that most of the examples show using variables from HttpContext that are always available (Browser, Browser Version etc.) and even though Microsoft and others seem to suggest this as the preferred "cache by custom string" method I can't find any working examples that allow the page to define the string. I have seen a few examples of people using session and claiming that it works (session is null for me) and context.user (some people say that user is null) but I don't see any practical way to deliver a string except by using Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("my_custom_string"). After a day of strugling with implementation in the main project I decided to build an isolated project for testing/proof of concept. In this project I was able to get my custom string working as long as I passed it as the string to SetVaryByCustom. The problem is that this doesn't really match any examples I've seen. The examples show "SomeKey" with "SomeValue" being returned by GetVaryByCustomString. What worked for me was essentially "SomeValue" with "SomeValue". Here was my code:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg != null)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

This worked the first time on the page, after setting the value of a dropdown which created a postback, but never after that. So the "OnselectedItemChanged" fired once and created a new set of cache entries based on the selection, but it never fired again. I tried modifying just about every cache parameter I could to make it work but no matter what series of settings I attempted (set cache declaratively, set caching in code, tried various combinations of VaryByParams, adding location, etc) I was never successful.
After attempting for 2 days to get this to work I decided it was time for a different approach. I have gone back to a more traditional/accepted approach.
I created 3 cache profiles in my web.config:

```
<caching>
        <cache disableExpiration="false" />
        <outputCache defaultProvider="RedisOutputCacheProvider" enableOutputCache="true" enableFragmentCache="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true">
          <providers>
            <add name="RedisOutputCacheProvider"
                  type="LAC.OutputCacheProvider, LAC"
                  connectionString="192.168.XX.XX:6379,connectTimeout=10000"
                  dbNumber="5"
                  keyPrefix="LAC:OutputCache:" />
          </providers>
        </outputCache>
        <outputCacheSettings>
          <outputCacheProfiles>
            <add name="Home" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="user" duration="86400"/>
            <add name="Results" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="user" duration="7200" />
            <add name="Details" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="user" duration="7200"/>
          </outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
```

So each page has a custom vary by user string that should help me cache a new page for an authenticated user vs an anonymous one.
Then I added a GetVaryByCustomString that looks like:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
        switch (arg)
        {
            case "user":
                var identity = context.User.Identity.Name != "" ? context.User.Identity.Name : "Anonymous";

            return string.Format("IsAuthenticated={0},Identity={1}", context.Request.IsAuthenticated, identity);
        }

            return string.Empty;
}
```

I am as close as I have ever been to having this working but it's still not 100%. The Home page works fine, the details page works fine, but the results page never caches. The results page has a filter containing 12 different dropdown lists. So it needs to store version of the page based on selections. I added a Timestamp to the top of all of my pages so I could see if the page was caching. The time on the results page changes every time I hit control-F5, which is not true on the other 2 pages. No cache entries are ever created and GetVaryByCustomString is never called. I have triple checked the code for some sort of "Turn cacheability Off" setting but as far as I can tell there is no code anywhere in the page that disables the cache. My global.asax file inherits from the correct class, my custom ouputcache provider seems to be adding the correct entries for the 2 pages that work. Of course now with VaryByParam="*" the key can be as long as the content thanks to viewstate (which has to be left on) BLECH!

So essentially I have caching set on three pages that are similar and one doesn't work. I have no idea where to look next. I am hoping someone like @kevinmontrose who really has a handle on this sort of stuff will take pity on me and give me a shove in a direction that will lead me to a solution.

**UPDATE:**
I have opened a case with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

have you been setting VaryByParam? i forget the details at the moment but i recall getting stuck before finding out that it is mandatory. (in *every* case i think.(?)) i think duration is also required. (i'm referring to directives in the .aspx page.)

Comment: just had a look on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - VaryByParam or VaryByControl is necessary.

Comment: Yes. I have set both duration and Varybyparam. I have tried Varybyparam with none, * and an ID. I'm begining to think the way the page is built my be at issue. Would be nice to find a way to pass the custom string so it could be read by httpcontext.

Comment: Also if I set varyByCustom to any value other than "user" on Details or Home it stops them from caching and GetVaryByCustomString is never called. If it's supposed to be an arbitrary value then why would it break if I set it to something different?

Comment: Something is just not right at all. If I use: varyByCustom="TestPage" varyByParam="*" varyByHeader="Cookie" location="Server" it fires GetVaryByCustomString if I remove varyByHeader="Cookie" it no longer calls that method.

Comment: Currently still investigating this with Microsoft. We have verified that a web forms app with a master page will not cache based on VaryByControl or VaryByParam. My project does not use mater pages but the nature of the way the controls are built dynamically is preventing the cache key (which is created automatically by the .Net run time) from being the same on return trips to the page.  We are investigating whether or not the key can be overridden in a custom output cache scenario. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on what schema is being used to create the key for the page.

Answer (score 0):

rereading your question i saw the issue: "I can't find any working examples that allow the page to define the string." i was rereading some articles and i'm pretty sure that's the wrong approach.

i haven't tested all of this but for ex, if you take the standard example:

`<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="minorversion" %>`

what seems to be happening is that you have just set the string to look for, and that's it.

when a request comes in, you check the HTTP *request header* - the Vary header, which is what you set in the page - and if it exists you do what you want.

```
<%@ Application language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, 
    string arg)
{
    // arg is your custom 'Vary' header.
    if(arg == "minorversion")
    {
        return "Version=" +
            context.Request.Browser.MinorVersion.ToString();
    }
    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
</script>
```

i just did a quick test of the basic example and added a label that is updated on page load with the current time. i refreshed the live page several times and the time did not change until 10 seconds had passed. so it definitely works. i think the key is that you set the value and you're done, but you can work with it if you want to.

... on second thought, i think you *create* the header in the page, and *return* the value from the global.asax. where?? i think it's sent to the *caching system* which decides if a new or cached page should be sent. in the example above the browser's minor version is checked and set and since there is a cached version available (after first load) it sends that, until 10 secs are up.

the docs for VaryByCustom is in a section for 'caching different versions of a page' so that's what this is doing. if someone with a different browser shows up, the browser version is checked - then the caching system checks to see if a version of the page *for that browser version* is available. if not, create a new page; if so, send the cached version.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what I'm looking for is a way to set the value returned by GetVaryByCustomString from the page itself. So some way to load a variable from httpContext so it becomes the string value of the cache. So something like HttpContext.Request.Items.Add("SearchString","Color=Red")

Comment: Unfortunately anything I add from the page comes back as null in one of the 2 (cachedvaryby and cachedobject) caching transactions--which breaks caching. I have also found that every time I add a cookie it breaks caching too, but I can't find any documentation that says you shouldn't add cookies on a page using outputcache.

Comment: just to check, do you know you can do simple caching with: `Cache["SearchString"] = "Red";` and get it back by `string currColor = Cache["SearchString"];`?

Comment: Yes I am already doing data caching, the issue is trying to cache the whole page and not just the data.